# I have a trouble with association with sequelize and postgres

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two tables defined, one for movies, one for characters, these are interconnected, by the MovieCharacter table.
Setting the tables to maintain a one-to-many relationship via belongstomany allows me to create a duplicate relationship, and I'm not getting around it.
I leave my code below, i have some experience with mongoose and nosql db but this is new for me.
Thanks!

charModel.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const CHARACTER_TABLE = 'character';

const CharacterSchema = {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  weight: {
    type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  history: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  image: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
};
```

modelMovie.js

```
class Character extends Model {
    static associate(models){
      this.belongsToMany(models.Movie, {
        as: "movies",
        through: "MovieCharacter",
        foreignKey: "characterId",
        otherKey: "movieId",
      });
    }
    static config(sequelize){
        return {
            sequelize,
            tableName: CHARACTER_TABLE,
            modelName: 'Character',
            timestamps: false,
        }
    }
}

const moment = require("moment");
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { GENRES_TABLE } = require("./genre.model");

const MOVIES_TABLE = "movie";

const MovieSchema = {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
  creationDate: {
    field: "creation_date",
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    get(){
      return moment(this.getDataValue('creationDate')).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
    },
    allowNull: false,
  },
  rating: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  image: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  type: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  genreId: {
    field: "genre_id",
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: GENRES_TABLE,
      key: "id",
    },
    onUpdate: "CASCADE",
    onDelete: "SET NULL",
  },
};

class Movie extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsToMany(models.Character, {
      as: "characters",
      through: "MovieCharacter",
      foreignKey: "movieId",
      otherKey: "characterId",
    });
    this.belongsTo(models.Genre, {
      as: "genre",
    });
  }
  static config(sequelize) {
    return {
      sequelize,
      tableName: MOVIES_TABLE,
      modelName: "Movie",
      timestamps: false,
    };
  }
}

module.exports = { MOVIES_TABLE, MovieSchema, Movie };
```

modelCharMov.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
const { CHARACTER_TABLE} = require('./character.model');
const { MOVIES_TABLE} = require('./movies.model')

const MOVIES_CHARACTERS_TABLE = 'movies_characters';


const MoviesCharactersSchema = {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  movieId:{
    field: 'movie_id',
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: MOVIES_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL'
  },
  characterId:{
    field: 'character_id',
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: CHARACTER_TABLE,
      key: 'id'
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL'
  }
};


class MovieCharacter extends Model {
  static config(sequelize) {
    return {
      sequelize,
      tableName: MOVIES_CHARACTERS_TABLE,
      modelName: 'MovieCharacter',
      timestamps: false
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want characters to be able to be related to multiple movies? If so, you will need to set up belongsToMany relationships on both Character and Movie, and belongsTo relationships on MovieCharacter for each. If characters can only belong to one movie, it will be different. Can provide assistance with some clarity.

Comment: Show how you add new records / update existing ones in `MovieCharacter`

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 BelongsTo associations on the junction table pointing to the tables that are using it to find one another. That would be my first guess because that is the only thing that would have been different in my code compared to yours if implementing this. If that doesn’t work, more details please sir